# Try Demo Customer Access

Tags: luma-theme, magento-2.1.7

I installed Magento 2 with sample data.
I used the Luma theme and changed everything, adding pages and other information.
I would like to remove the Try Demo Customer Access block but find nothing from the settings.
Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove it from admin

```
Admin >> Content >> Widgets >> Open Login Info >> Layout Updates
```

You can delete it from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was going crazy to find this block, I searched in all the magento files also through ssh but nothing. I did not think it could be a static block.

Comment: It is Widget. Is it working for you?

Comment: Accept my answer.

Comment: I'm new user excuse, how do I do it?

Comment: Actually, it's a widget injecting a block into the login page. If you only want to disable it, just go to the block and disable *login-data* (disabling widgets isn't possible).

Comment: And you should think about deleting the demo account or changing it's email address and revoking all session tokens by clicking *Force Sign-In* in its user details to disable misuse of the demo user.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Admin >> Content >> Blocks >> Login info and edit the content.